# Зачем нужно вставлять несколько изображений с разными расширениями в ICO-файл для favicon? Почему не использовать одно 48х48?

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Один ICO-файл может содержать несколько изображений с различными разрешениями.
Майкрософт [рекомендует](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg491740(v=vs.85).aspx) создавать один ICO-файл содержащий в себе 3 разрешения: 16х16, 32х32 и 48х48. Но почему не использовать один ICO-файл с одним единственным разрешением 48х48? Ведь браузер сам подгоняет размер картинки.

Comment: Лучше использовать все 2^n начиная с 8 и заканчивая 256, для наилучшей адаптации под разные размеры иконок. Например при маленьком разрешении выводить только картинку, а при большом можно добавить текст и картинку сделать "покрасивше"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На устройствах в высоким разрещением даже иконка 48×48 будет выглядеть очень плохо. На маленьких устройствах еще может понадобиться иконка 16×16 и она может отличаться от масштабированной. Например она может быть сильно упрощена и будет выгдядеть более понятно, чем размытое нечто.

Вот пример не из веба (хороший пример с сайта пока не нашел) - иконка FAR Manager. В ней всего два размера 32×32 и 16×16 (см. две первых иконки на рисунке).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если оставить только первый размер, то в заголовке получится иконка как на приведенном рисунке справа.

Если иконка 48×48 не имеет слишком маленьких деталей и при автоматическом масштабировании имеет приличный вид, можно в favicon.ico оставлять только её. Однако при этом не забывайте про иконки более крупного размера (иконки нужны не только для заголовка браузера).

См. также:

1. [Favicons, Touch Icons, Tile Icons и т. д. Что выбрать?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/260777/)

Comment: Я читал эту статью, в ней не объясняется почему нужно использовать ICO с тремя разрешениями. Там говорится лишь о том, что 16х16 выглядит плохо в некоторых местах (панели задач, рабочем столе). А то о чём вы пишите: "устройствах в высоком резрешении" насколько я понял вы имеете ввиду ретина дисплеи, так это вообще другая тема.

Comment: Не совсем другая, но конечно к favicon.ico не имеет отношения. Я написал это для полноты картины. Ретина - скорее маркетологический термин одной известной конторы. Высокие разрешения есть не только у них.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы для разных отображений иконки или ярлыка корректно отображалось изображение. Уменьшение больших или увеличение маленьких растровых изображений всегда даёт размытый результат.

Лучше всего взять векторное изображение, сохранить его в нескольких разрешениях и скомпоновать из них ico файл.

Я пользуюсь простым правилом выбора разрешений для файлов ico

- для веба (favicon.ico): 16x16, 32x32
- для Windows (папки, ярлыки, иконки программ): 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64,
  128x128, 256x256

Вот в этом [видео](https://vk.com/ru_icons8?z=video-128808289_456239017) показано как ведёт себя директория с пользовательской иконкой при различных разрешениях.

Comment: Спасибо. Учёл. Поправил.